# MS Access 2010 Module Case Statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, select-case

I am trying to perform the following function in MS Access 2010 for Birthday=5/5/1958 and getting a return value of "unknown" instead of "Dog." Any help on this CASE statement?

```
Public Function whichChineseZodiacSign(Birthday As Date)

Select Case whichChineseZodiacSign
Case #2/18/1958# To #2/7/1959#
    whichChineseZodiacSign = "Dog"

Case Else
    whichChineseZodiacSign = "Unknown"
End Select
End Function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function whichChineseZodiacSign(Birthday As Date) As String

    Select Case Birthday
    Case #2/18/1958# To #2/7/1959#
        whichChineseZodiacSign = "Dog"
    Case Else
        whichChineseZodiacSign = "Unknown"
    End Select

End Function
```

In your case you had false condition in the `Select Case`.